# weblogic disable ports exposed

Tags: linux, weblogic

Im pretty new to WebLogic.

I'm working on a customer issue, where I need to hide the ports exposed by Weblogic to the external world below are the few ports

```
Port 1705 : Occas AdminServer listening on ALL interfaces.  
Port 1706 : Occas oam-1 server listening on ALL interfaces.  
Port 5556 : Occas NodeManager listening on ALL interfaces.
```

Comment: **Need urgent help

Answer (score 0):

This is traditionally a job for a firewall, which only allows access to the ports required for external communication (port 80 in the case of a web server.)

You may be able to use the Linux built-in firewall (netfilter/iptables) to achieve the same thing.